# Using AJAX/JQuery to post form data to a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I pieced this together from other answers on this site and various tutorials. Not sure why it isn't working, and I've not had any luck with other methods.

Here is parts of my page html:

```
    <form id="newMovie" >
        Title:<input type='text' id='title'/>
        Genres:<input type='text' id='genres'/>
        Cast:<input type='text' id='cast'/>
        Director:<input type='text' id='director'/>
        Metascore:<input type='text' id='metascore'/>
        <input type="button" value="Send" id="theButton"/>
    </form>
    ...
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="tr1td1">
                <p>..</p>
            </td>
            ...
```

On "theButton" click, I want to grab the values from the inputs in the form and POST it to a php script, here is my AJAX:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#theButton").click(function(){

                var titleData = $('#title');
                alert(titleData);
```

I've got an alert here for debugging, this alert doesn't even pop, so it seems to be failing before we even get here?

```
                var genresData = $('#genres');
                var castData = $('#cast');
                var directorData = $('#director');
                var metascoreData = $('#metascore');

                var dataIn = {
                    title : titleData.val();
                    genres : genreData.val();
                    cast : castData.val();
                    director : directorData.val();
                    metascore : metascoreData.val();
                }
                var dataOut = $('#tr1td1');
                $.post("..../insert.php", dataIn, function(data, status) {
                    dataOut.html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In the PHP script, I wil try and grab the values like so:

```
$titleData=$_POST['title'];
$genresData=$_POST['genres'];
$castData=$_POST['cast'];
$directorData=$_POST['director'];
$metascoreData=$_POST['metascore'];
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Oh.. I forgot browsers have consoles these days *Bangs head with desk*, gimme a sec

Comment: Uncaught Syntax Error: unexpected ; at line 27, which is the first line in the "dataIn" brackets

Comment: I downvote Javascript questions where it's obvious that they forgot to check the console before posting.

Comment: Well as made clear from the comments, I totally forgot there was a console in the browser. I'm not a web dev! Thank you though for providing an explanation for the downvote, nothing worse than a ghost downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment points to the error:

> Uncaught Syntax Error: unexpected ; at line 27, which is the first line in the "dataIn" brackets

You have errant semi-colons in your object construction:

```
var dataIn = {
    title : titleData.val();
    genres : genreData.val();
    cast : castData.val();
    director : directorData.val();
    metascore : metascoreData.val();
}
```

Should be:

```
var dataIn = {
    title : titleData.val(),
    genres : genreData.val(),
    cast : castData.val(),
    director : directorData.val(),
    metascore : metascoreData.val()
};
```

Object literals are a list of comma-separated properties as a single overall line of code, not individual lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript object properties are delimited with commas `,` not semicolons. Also, another gotcha in some browsers - do not delimit the final property.

Comment: Yep, okay fair enough. But maybe use a different way of showing that like `<url-omitted>` or someth!

Answer (score 1):

Your way is too long, you are missing name="" attrib in  tags and

add name="" to  tag 
you can make it more simple like below

Firstly change your

```
<input type="button" value="Send" id="theButton"/>
```

with

```
<button type="button" id="theButton" name="SubBtn" onclick="postsomething();">Send</button>
```

After

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postsomething() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../insert.php', //your php file
                data: $('#newMovie').serialize(), //here your form id
                success: function (answer) {
                    $("#result").html(answer) //if you wanna return data from your php file
                }
            })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I would prefer to do it in a way where the event is added to the button, so I'm not limited to forms in the future